# Multiple records update into a column with inner join DB2

Tags: db2, db2-400, iseries-navigator

I have written this update statement to update records in DB2.

```
UPDATE schemaname.tablename
SET fillerinfo = myfillerinfo
FROM schemaname.tablename,schemaname.tablename1
WHERE ID = uid1
AND PID=uuplanid
AND ACCTNO=uacctno
```

However, when running on AS400 DB2.

I have Data like this:

```
        Table1  | Table2
     fillerinfo |myfillerinfo
     -----------|-------------
         A      |   b
         c     |   D
       E       |   f
```

Like above i have 500K records.

Its showing error: Statement can not be executed.

I'm getting error:

> Keyword FROM not expected. Valid tokens: USE SKIP WAIT WITH WHERE.
>   Cause . . . . . :   The keyword FROM was not expected here.  A syntax
>   error was detected at keyword FROM.  The partial list of valid tokens
>   is USE SKIP WAIT WITH WHERE. This list assumes that the statement is
>   correct up to the unexpected keyword.  The error may be earlier in the
>   statement but the syntax of the statement seems to be valid up to this
>   point. Recovery  . . . :   Examine the SQL statement in the area of
>   the specified keyword.  A colon or SQL delimiter may be missing. SQL
>   requires reserved words to be delimited when they are used as a name.
>   Correct the SQL statement and try the request again.

So I refereed this link to see if it helps:  https://oscarvalles.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/db2-update-with-inner-joins/

But, this example in the above link is showing to update single records.

How can I update multiple records in a column with join? Please suggest.

Comment: add more detail like table structure and sample data if possible

Answer (score 1):

DB2 is a bit different than MS SQL Server. You can update from a subselect like this

```
UPDATE schemaname.tablename
SET fillerinfo = (SELECT myfillerinfo
                  FROM schemaname.tablename,schemaname.tablename1
                  WHERE ...)
WHERE ID = uid1
AND PID=uuplanid
AND ACCTNO=uacctno
```

I suspect you can determine the correct WHERE clause in the subselect.

Answer (score 0):

Try INNER JOIN instead

```
UPDATE T1
SET 
fillerinfo = T2.myfillerinfo
FROM schemaname.tablename t1
INNER JOIN schemaname.tablename1 T2
ON T1.ID = T2.uid1
WHERE T1.PID=T2.uuplanid
AND T1.ACCTNO=T2.uacctno
```

Or try MERGE

```
MERGE INTO schemaname.tablename t1
    USING
    (
        SELECT
            uid1,
            uuplanid,
            uacctno,
            myfillerinfo 
            FROM schemaname.tablename1 
    )T2
        ON T1.ID = T2.uid1
    WHEN MATCHED AND T1.PID=T2.uuplanid
            AND T1.ACCTNO=T2.uacctno
        THEN UPDATE
            SET T1.fillerinfo = T2.myfillerinfo
```

OR try this

```
UPDATE schemaname.tablename T1
    SET 
        T1.fillerinfo = (SELECT T2.myfillerinfo FROM schemaname.tablename1 T2
                            WHERE T1.ID = T2.uid1
                            AND T1.PID=T2.uuplanid
                            AND T1.ACCTNO=T2.uacctno
                        )
        WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM schemaname.tablename1 T2
                            WHERE T1.ID = T2.uid1
                            AND T1.PID=T2.uuplanid
                            AND T1.ACCTNO=T2.uacctno
        )
```

Comment: Have you tried this from iSeries navigator? Is this worked? I have updated my question with exact error.

Comment: I've used this type of query in SSMS. Please add the Table design to the question so that I can give more detailed answer

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'll check these queries. I have just refereed this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql